# ESLint rule: maximum nesting path for file

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there such a rule that checks the file path nesting level? For example:

Examples of incorrect code for this rule:

```
import { notifyDevelopers } from '../../../../../utils/ajax'
```

Examples of correct code for this rule:

```
import { notifyDevelopers } from './../utils/ajax'
import { notifyDevelopers } from 'utils/ajax'
```

I found only this package:
https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import

but it seems that this package does not have such rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.eslintrc`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": ["../../../*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`no-restricted-modules` rule, also support this